# SBJson - has memory leaks?

Tags: ios, sbjson

I just cloned the git repository for the SBJson framework and imported the source code into my application. Ran a Static Memory profiler and got a little scared from the results I saw.
See the picture

[image]

How is this possible? I doubt the developer of this very well known library didn't see this? And indeed, if a run a memory profile it shows memory leaks from this library.

Any ideas?
Thx

Comment: warrenm answered it correctly below, but I'd just like to point out that version 3.2 of SBJson makes it a compile error to attempt to compile without ARC support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using SBJSON in a project that doesn't have [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) enabled. Since ARC removes the need to call `release` explicitly, code written for ARC (like SBJSON) causes memory leaks when used in a non-ARC project. You should [convert your project to use ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) with the built-in refactoring tool (Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC, then explicitly set the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag on any of your source that is not yet ARC-ready.

Comment: Alternatively you can downgrade to SBJson v3.0.4 which is non-ARC.

Comment: You could, but there is no disadvantage to converting a project to ARC. The chief advantage is that you're able to take advantage of fixes introduced in more recent versions of your dependencies instead of staying frozen in time.